# Oracle11.2g post-installation problem on Oracle Linux kernel

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, installation, linux, sqlplus

After installation of Oracle 11.2g in silent mode on the Oracle Linux kernel, I have the following error:

```
[u01/app/oracle/product/11/bin] $ sqlplus

sqlplus error while loading shared libraries: libsqlplus.so: cannot open shared  
object file: No such file or directory
```

However, the shared object seems to be setup correctly:

```
[/u01/app/oracle/product/11/lib] $ ls -lrt /u01/app/oracle/product/11/lib | grep sqlplus  
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall   1475820 Aug  1  2009 libsqlplus.a  
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 oracle oinstall   1218075 Aug  1  2009 libsqlplus.so
```

The user is oracle:

```
[oracle ~]$ id oracle  
uid=501(oracle) gid=501(oinstall) groups=501(oinstall),502(dba)
```

The environment variables are:

```
[oracle ~]$ env  
USER=oracle  
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/11/lib  
ORACLE_SID=orcl  
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle      
PATH=/usr/lib/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin
    :/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: /home/oracle/bin
    :/u01/app/oracle/product/11/bin  
HOME=/home/oracle  
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11
```

kernel version:

```
2.6.32-300.3.1.el6uek.i686
```

***UPDATE FOR ANSWER ***

```
[oracle@orcus lib]$ ldd /u01/app/oracle/product/11/bin/sqlplus   
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb771f000)  
    libsqlplus.so => /u01/app/oracle/product/11/lib/libsqlplus.so (0xb766e000)  
libclntsh.so.11.1 => not found  
    libnnz11.so => /u01/app/oracle/product/11/lib/libnnz11.so (0xb7415000)  
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x4c5dc000)  
    libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x4c616000)  
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x4c5e3000)  
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/libnsl.so.1 (0x4caef000)  
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x4c44a000)  
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x4c424000)  
    libclntsh.so.11.1 => not found
```

*** after chmod /u01/app/oracle/product/11/lib/libclntsh* ***

```
$ ldd /u01/app/oracle/product/11/bin/sqlplus   
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7831000)  
    libsqlplus.so => /u01/app/oracle/product/11/lib/libsqlplus.so (0xb7780000)  
    libclntsh.so.11.1 => /u01/app/oracle/product/11/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1 (0xb5a7b000)  
    libnnz11.so => /u01/app/oracle/product/11/lib/libnnz11.so (0xb582e000)  
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x4c5dc000)  
    libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x4c616000)  
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x4c5e3000)  
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/libnsl.so.1 (0x4caef000)  
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x4c44a000)  
    libaio.so.1 => /lib/libaio.so.1 (0x4c446000)  
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x4c424000)
```

Any idea why SQLPlus is complaining about `libsqlplus.so`?

Answer (score 2):

Make libclntsh executable:

```
chmod +rx /u01/app/oracle/product/11/lib/libclntsh*
```

Then check the above commented ldd command again.

Answer (score 0):

You should be searching for libclntsh.so.11.1 in /u01/app/oracle/product/11/lib  ,

Comment: Are you sure the silent install completed? The library should also be in $ORACLE_HOME/lib. Check the silent install log file.

Comment: @phil  libclntsh.so.11.1 found after mod changed

Comment: @phil found one silent install log file called : silentInstall2012-01-24_06-14-37PM.log
actually full of errors. But now the $ sqlplus /nolog worked, but denied access to sqlplus /as sysdba

Comment: What's the error message when you "sqlplus / as sysdba" ?

Comment: @phil ERROR:
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact
but it gave me the prompt to log and no user name and password already set in the response file  match

Comment: @phil Sorry for being late. But I finally reinstall in usual way (not in response file). The DB run well. Thx for the help and time shared (it's make me more aware of the product as well)